# How to get data on a reference first before executing other code?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need to get all data from a specific location on my Firebase and put that data inside an `ArrayList` before processing it. I have something like this:

```
final ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
Firebase ref = rootRef.child("data");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {}
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snap) {
        for (Object obj : snap.getChildren) {
            data.add(obj.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
);
processData(data);
```

I'm fairly a newbie with this kind of stuff, but I think this is not good especially if there's tons of data to be read and if the user's connectivity is slow.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Loading the data takes as much time as it takes. If you want your `onDataChange()` to be called sooner, you should probably be loading less data, e.g. `ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(10).add...`. But this depends on the data structure of course.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want to retrieve all data from the database and store those data in a List before processing it.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what your code currently does?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Firebase but I would be shocked if they did not have some sort of equivalent as the Android loader callback "onLoadFinished(){...}". You should find what is similar in Firebase, and call your "processData(data)" from within it.

Comment: The `onDataChange()` method will be called when the current data for the location has been retrieved. This data is then passed in as the `DataSnapshot`.